# Вывести данные из всех таблиц определённой базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. В моей базе данных существует около 7000 таблиц. Мне необходимо создать PHP страницу, на которой должны отображаться данные всех этих таблиц. Как все эти таблицы туда вывести?

Comment: Прочитать, вывести. Какой именно шаг вызывает вопросы?

Comment: Что-то вряд ли такое надо делать...

Comment: Список таблиц или прям данные? А сколько записей в каждой таблице?

Answer (score 1):

можешь сгенерить view 
в которой будет select ... from table1
union all  select ... from table2 и т.д.